# Can a Dedicated Server or VPS have more then one IP active

Tags: networking, dns, ip, esxi

I am working with VMWare ESXI 6.0 to create Virtual Machines.
I was trying to create a virtual machine with more then one IP binded to it. One VPS 3 IPs attached to it. I have created 3 nics and added IPs to them. Everything is cool, but i can not make more then one IP active at a time. Why? Is it even possible for a PC/VPS to be reached via 3 different IPs pointing to it?

To answer this questions i have purchased a dedicated server from very known Hosting provider and ordered 5 IPs to this dedicated server. There also i can not reach the server from more then one IP address.

Is it possible for a PC/Dedicated Server or Virtual Machine to have more then one IP and to be reached with all of them ?

Thanks for your time and i hope i have explained my question well enough.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> Is it even possible for a PC/VPS to be reached via 3 different IPs pointing
>   to it?

Yes, it is. There is nothing strange with a machine having multiple NICs, or even having multiple IP per NIC. The term for this is 'multi-homed'.

There should be no difference between this for a physical machine or a cirtual one.

> I can not reach the server **from** more then one IP address.

From or on?

Most trivial way to demonstrate multi homed:

```
  S  
  e NIC1 (10.0.1.1) ----- Network 10.0.1.x  ----- PC A
  r
  v
  e NIC2 (10.0.2.1) ----- Network 10.0.2.x  ----- PC B
  r
```

(Notice the different networks.)
PC A can reach the server.
PC B can reach the server.

Instead of physical NIC we might as well assign different IPs (and range) to one NIC.  Different NICs are easier to grasp though.

The server will still have only one active default gateway. So when you assign multiple network ranges you want to make sure that your routes are properly configures.

And finally, multiple IPs on a single NIC can get interesting depending on the IP stack. You might reach the server on one IP, and get answer from another one.

Still, the basic answer is: Heck yes. That should work.

Comment: Do i have to assign different networks to every nic in order to make the VPS accessible from multiple IPs? Can you please give me any guidence or link for some. I am using DHCP connection. Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, you can put them on the same network. But then routing will get very interesting. (Also, why would you, multiple NIC on the same network has no advantage at all).

Comment: I am trying different methods without knowing which one is the easiest or the best. If you can give me any guide that will do the work, i'll be very thankful. Note that i am using VMWare ESXI 6.0 and i am making my tests with virtual machines. I have two physical vswitches and two different networks. Everyone of them can distribute up to 5 IP addresses.